# Portable/binary format for Flutter widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, portability, file-format

I wonder, is there any way to transfer/inject a custom widget in your app as a separate file?
I understand there are many complications for doing it but, at least for stateless widgets, it might be possible.

I understand I can put just dart file of widget or use as a Flutter package but I would like to work with widget more like with an asset (image/font/etc).

I guess, there isn't a clear, straight answer for this but if you know some GitHub project or thread about this issue, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're looking for something like a server driven UI(Please ignore if not)... If yes, this might be your thing (Which let's you build a dynamic UI on the fly..): `https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_widget/versions` ...  This is a good write up about it: `https://medium.com/@danieln.llewellyn/in-this-article-im-going-to-demonstrate-a-way-of-driving-the-ui-of-flutter-from-the-backend-43478b46e202`

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yeah, it's not exactly what I'm looking for but the idea of "rendering" UI on a server is actually worth considering for my project.